# PDF editing directly then deleting edits still leaves pdf corrupted

Tags: pdf

My PDF looked fine until I edited it, and now it still appears to be corrupted even after I took out my edits. A file diff program is saying that the two files are the same, but only one is displaying the information.

To reproduce:

1) Open PDF and make sure there is stuff inside of it

2) Open PDF in a text editor and add text at the top

3) Open PDF normally and it is empty

4) delete text added in step 2

5) PDF is still corrupted despite having SAME file contents

This also happens if I literally copy and paste the code from a PDF into a different file and try to open that. It won't open.

Is there any way to be able to be able to add text to a PDF and have it not corrupt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDF is a *binary* format. Even if it looks quite text'ish, it is *not text*. In particular PDF files usually contain binary data streams, e.g. for images or embedded fonts or compressed arbitrary content. Furthermore, PDFs rely on PDF objects starting at offsets noted in a cross reference table or stream in the file.

Many text editors, though, do not only apply the changes you type in to a document but also do other stuff, like unifying line breaks (DOS CRLF or Unix LF or Max CR), replacing byte sequences they could not interpret by a special character (e.g. the Unicode REPLACEMENT CHARACTER) or dropping them altogether, etc.

The former (unifying line breaks) moves the data without updating the cross reference information, rendering it useless. If the bytes interpreted as line break characters were actually parts of binary stream data, the stream data also is damaged.

The latter (byte sequence replacement) usually damages contents of streams in the PDF with compressed data or other sensitive binary data beyond repair. Depending on the sequence length, this also moves data and so invalidates cross references.

Thus, using a **text** editor to edit a PDF usually is a sure way to break a PDF.

> Is there any way to be able to be able to add text to a pdf and have it not corrupt?

Yes, using PDF aware software, e.g. Adobe Acrobat but there also are others. If you prefer a programming approach, use a good general purpose PDF library. There are such libraries for many programming platforms.

For a very few types of changes, one can also use a hex editor (only replacing some bytes, not inserting or removing anything), but you really should know what you are doing.